# [iOS+TestFlight]What's the best way to prevent from submitting a binary with debug codes

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

Back in the days when the only way to distribute a beta app was to use AdHoc build, I used to make a separated "AdHoc" target. This was a good prevention to avoid submitting a wrongly configured binary because AdHoc binary would never accepted for the store.

But now that the distribution is TestFlight, the way to make a beta binary became the same as the one to make a store binary.
We still can prepare specific targets to include/exclude debug features but both goes to the same way in iTunes Connect eventually so we have to pay attention not to submit the beta binary as a store version.

Do you have any idea to avoid this situation? Or you are just being careful enough?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of having a beta build is to test as closely as what the general audience will eventually be seeing. Therefore, I am not quite convinced that having a debug configuration for only TestFlight is necessary or a very good practice.

If you do have custom logic/feature that you want to be available only with internal beta users, maybe consider uploading it as a separate app with a different app ID?

For example, for production app:

```
com.mycompany.myawseomeapp.production
```

for staging app:

```
com.mycompany.myawseomeapp.staging
```

Then you can provide different logic against the two different apps and at the meantime share the majority of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can still distribute AdHoc builds for OTA installs or install one-off Development builds with Xcode and use debug-enabled configurations, but I'd avoid having anything in a TestFlight build that's not intended for the App Store.

Your TestFlight releases should mirror what you're going to release. Otherwise, you're really beta testing different code than you're releasing and there's too much risk that debug code will get out in the wild.

Take advantage of development, AdHoc and release builds. Don't distribute all your test builds through TestFlight if you need debug options enabled.